# how to get facebook likes and share count for given time range e.g.week,day,moth,custom time range

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently fetching likes and share counts for give URL using the following endpoint.
I also fetched Facebook tokens but no use.

```
$graph_url= "https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.facebook.com&format=json";
```

I also looked into Facebook developers but i couldn't find any solutions.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/insights

Comment: Please consider revising your question.

Comment: why no one answered my question

Answer (score 0):

To get likes day by day, you call `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{your-page-id}/insights/page_fan_adds` with and valid access_token.

You can filter your results by using the parameters `since` and `until`. This metric is provided only in daily mode. To see the metric in a month, you need to get all 30 days and sum it.

Please, read the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/insights to see how you can combine the different types of metrics.